# SQL Searching for results with apostrophes

Tags: sql

I am trying to automate a problem at work and have an SQL question. I am getting a list from one of our vendors strips all of the apostrophes out of the info.

So when I search for "oneil" and my database has "o'neil"

```
select * from db where name = "oneil"
```

I know how to fix that by hand, but how would I make it work when I don't know where the apostrophe is at?

I hope I explained that right.

Comment: Which implementation of SQL? Anyway, just replace apostrophes with nothing, and match against that, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could first strip the apostrophes from the name before doing the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM db
WHERE REPLACE(name, '''', '') = 'oneil';
```

### Demo

Note that in most versions of SQL, a literal apostrophe is represented inside a string literal using two apostrophes doubled-up `''`.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, use a temp table with apostrophes replaced:

```
select *,
       derived_name = REPLACE(t.name,'''','')
into #temp
from table t
```

Then you can do: `select * from #temp where derived_name='oneil'`

Note that the apostrophe is also the escape character in sql server.